# Pancake, swapETHForExactTokens and swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens

Tags: web3js

How does it determine when to call swapETHForExactTokens and when to call swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens?